# Which bank is the hardest to hack?

Tags: hacker-experience

The bank with the highest Hasher version that I have found so far is

> the Ultimate Bank, with a Hasher of 8.0

I have found multiple other banks with lower versions, but that is the highest I have seen. I know that the higher the bank's Hasher version, the higher Cracker you need to hack an account on that bank. I would rather my money *not* be stolen, so **which bank has the highest Hasher version?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the Ultimate Bank

It goes in order of

Lowest

1. First International Bank
2. HEBC
3. American Express
4. Swiss
5. Ultimate

Highest

It is hard to protect your money. It is better to either not your bank account # leaked in the first place or use bitcoin for almost everything and everytime you use your bank account afterward close it and make a new one.